# Insufficient Privileges for Public Group Memberships Page

Tags: force.com, security, authorization

A user is a part of multiple public groups in Salesforce and has a custom profile. When the user navigates to the personal information page and clicks on the 'Go To List' link available under the 'Public Group Membership' related list, Salesforce throws a insufficient privileges error page. The user is able to click on the 'Show More' link and Salesforce refreshes the section with more records. This way the user can see all his group membership records.

Wonder why the user can't navigate to the 'Go To List' page and see all of the records rather than having to click N number of times on the Show More link.

Is there any profile permission that needs to be provided? I guess NO.

Comment: I would hazard a guess at saying the new User Sharing feature might have caused a glitch (assuming you're on Summer 14, and probably if you changed the default model to private). Barring that, my next guess would be that the user is being directed to a list view they have no access to (Setup > Manage Users > Users > List Views). This would probably happen if there were a list view configured that they initially had access to but then it was changed so they didn't.

Answer (score -1):

Grasping at straws here: sharing rules and org wide defaults on hte groups obj?